# jquery tmpl with if else

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I'm trying to cache my markup into a $.template. Inside of that, I'd like to add a conditional where, if a variable is empty, the output is reflected with this.

Here is a snippet of my attempt. When I run this, the event type is either correct, or blank. "(No Moderators Listed)" never shows up.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var markup = '<div class="new_line general_heading">' +
                 '{{if EventType != ""}}' +
                     '${$EventType}' +
                 '{{else}}' +
                     '(No Moderators Listed)' +
                 '{{/if}}' +
             '</div>' +
             '<div class="gray_rule allclear"></div>';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a small error in your template that *could* be causing issues:

```
var markup = '<div class="new_line general_heading">' +
                 '{{if EventType != ""}}' +
                     '${EventType}' +
                 '{{else}}' +
                     '(No Moderators Listed)' +
                 '{{/if}}' +
             '</div>' +
             '<div class="gray_rule allclear"></div>'
```

Changed `${$EventType}` to `${EventType}`. After that change, the template seems to work fine.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/tx97s/

Comment: Heh. First of all, I should have been doing this for the ${Faculty} variable. Oops. Second of all, dropping in this code worked, thanks. I was using the ${$ syntax from the [jQuery.tmpl()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/#options-items) site. Keeping that syntax broke the template. Using your syntax worked, so yes, +1 nice catch!